# How to use library fmt with clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, fmt

My code is like

```
#include "fmt/compile.h"

int main() {
  using namespace fmt::literals;
  auto result = fmt::format("{}"_cf, FMT_VERSION);
  printf("%s", result.data());
}
```

It cannot compile with clang. The compilation result can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxdpgOaUIETMQEGT5%2BXLaY9nkM1bUEBWGR0XoKNXUNWc2DXT1FJRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANTmZlQsBAD0aCwJdJgAdAj7JhoAgvcPwQQ7LEzBEDN7AOxWjx2Oy8KSMO2YbAUCSYyx2hwIIBAtEI0TEChMawBDyBTC8RB2xEwCi8tDeGIAInCjoj%2BMQPgQIHd/iZfuT9gB9ZBUUg7ABiAFkACrsgBq2AASkIAJIAeVCMwxWKBCWIryojLMZnMAFZ0ZqeYTiaSrugmDVvgrMc8WWzHhw5rRONreH4OFpSKhOG5rNYdgoFktMHszGseKQEW77XMANYgMy/K6h2JrNa/SSxbWSLgANkz%2Bk4khdml4no4vAUIA04eLczgsBgiBQqHOlzIFAgZwu9BiwC4GjMfDoBGiFYgEWLpAiwVqAE9OGGzmxBDKGLQ55HSFgPkZxBv8ITKgA3IkTzCqCp4lbu16tCfIiLEWceLDz3gEVUsV9zKgGYAKEV4JgADuMoJIwr4yIIIhiOwUiQfIShqBOugDgYRgoD6lj6HgEQVrAELsPCpDHjE75eAw0YzHMqAJO0FYcAAtIM6AUqYljWGYGg7AxMrAOWrQVO0LgMO4niNP4ImTH0MTNDkqQCCMTSJMk8kMFJxT9GMAmVAInTDGJowtG0VRDN0wS9BpMm2KZikDKZ6nTFwcz%2Bosyx6O%2BmArDwDpOkWG6lqosTZgx2aSDswDIMgOx9lcZg7BA3rsVhOy4IQJDBqGPIeC23YZWYMxvjWMYgCmiYpuVFUVfmHCFqQn7alWrruqW5aVtWka1g2EBIAsBAJHi5AuPgRCqugej8FBojiHBE0ISo6gbihpBAY%2BCRftVzqkE1JacDKeL9W8qBUDsgXBaF4WRdFGixfF2VdtEeUFe1WhUaQCCYEwWAxN81W1fVjUTi1thtRGL3FWYACcVwQzmKaSBDEOxJIayxEF1VrH5zWcIVHWkHWUBdUgnatoNHbNvdMRbIYvaSBoVY0KSI6UOOG5TswxDrguzZLgQK5rhOW7U7u7r7oJeDHvR7pnhew4Tjejobvej4c8%2BXlvh%2B60/kwf4AcBoHgdwvCzdB03SLNijzchJX6NTGFJTY954VABEgERJEgGRFGvTRdGcExBAsWs5JsVYlicdxvH8cZzgQK4tnNIE5lTJpym5Gk8ep6pDkp%2BUOkdDZBlKbn7R6WZhTSXZXQZ%2BMdTZzJzkBm5zQeWrPkcJt20epwp0hWFVNglIVzXVxCWYTYKXDel6zNDsd2thlaxPaDUakLGZjar9vD/VtgPY8DVbL518DdSAvUHaTxPdqErArD35398A0WSEPQ%2B8Jgk%2BjeNsgm7BZuyBbSFFrWxWkwNahs24d13hwPafU8Q7COidIKvcdgPyfi/Eec9crrEXjjMGb0PpfUoG3P6IAGo738nvCsB8iqrxAJIMwVxfi5jWPGbUOYpCSGzOjTGO0yzPRXgrMwPCu58MPnMEiKRnCSCAA%3D%3D%3D)

How can I make it work with clang. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build of fmt depends on a bunch of macros. Here, build fails because `operator () ""_cf` is not defined in the clang version. If you look at the code you'll see it depends on macro `FMT_USE_NONTYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS` for whatever reason.

Probably `godbolt` at inclusion of fmt doesn't declare the macro to be true for clang.

Regardless, if you simply add the line `#define FMT_USE_NONTYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS true` before including `fmt` the code will compile on clang too. This is not recommended solution, the macro should be defined at build level, not directly in the code.